# BeautifulSoup4 doesn't find elements properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using requests and bs4 to extract the first preview from the link http://duckduckgo.com/?q=who+is+harry+potter

However, when i try to use bs4's find method to find he div with the class 'result__snippet', it returns None. But when I saved the whole webpage to my hard disk and opened it directly and parsed it with bs4, `soup.find('div', class_='result__snippet').get_text()` returns the perfect output.

Any help?

Comment: What do you get when you print `soup.text`? Some websites don't like being scraped and will return different content than if you visit them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you link to appears to use JavaScript to build the search results, so the page you retrieve using BeautifulSoup doesn't actually contain the search results yet.

If you look at the content of the page that you've retrieved (`print(soup.text)`) you can see that they suggest that if you don't have JavaScript enabled to use http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=who+is+harry+potter.

Scraping this URL should provide you with the content that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) in combination with BeautifulSoup. Try this, it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=who+is+harry+potter&ia=web'

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
ua1 = UserAgent()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', str(ua1.random))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result__snippet')))
        print('Page is ready!')
        break 
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Loading took too much time!')
html = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
driver.close()

b_html = bs(html,'html.parser') 
x = b_html.find_all('div', class_='result__snippet')[0].get_text()
```

Output:

```
Harry Potter is a series of fantasy novels written by British author J. K. Rowling. The novels chronicle the life of a young wizard, Harry Potter, ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is over-engineered. I used the accepted answer and added `/html/` to my url and it works fine. My own code is 7-8 lines.